# Automator workflow to use VLC to turn ogg to mp3

Tags: automator, vlc, mp3

I tried using these scripts posted before but they didn't work for me.

```
cd ~/Downloads/Van Halen - Jamie's Cryin'/step
for f in *.ogg; do ffmpeg -i "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

or

```
unzip "Van Halen - Jamies Cryin (OGG) (Remix Stems).rar" -d mc
cd mc/
find . -type f -iname '*.ogg' -execdir sh -c \
    'ffmpeg -v 8 -i "$1" "${1%.*}.mp3" && rm -- "$1" && echo "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Is there any way one can make it a quick action using VLC and Automator?

Comment: How do these scripts "not work"?  Why would wrapping them in Automator make them work better?  What research have you done about them?

Comment: I'd be inclined to just use [XLD](https://tmkk.undo.jp/xld/index_e.html) instead. You *can* use it from the command line, but it's far simpler to just drag & drop. Also, if you're practising your remix skills, you don't want to be working from mp3, use wav or aif instead.